# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append' Trying to write to .JSON file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script where I am trying to write to a .JSON file called alerted_comments.json
I had this working on Windows, but when I have moved it to Ubuntu I am getting the error in the title. 
I am kind of new at this and am a little stuck. I know that its an issue with lists and dictionaries but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated

I am using python 3.6 on Ubuntu.

My current code related to this problem is here.

```
with open(save_path, 'r') as fp:
    alerted_comments = json.load(fp)

for comment in comment_stream:
    if comment.id in alerted_comments:
        continue

    if comment.author:  # if comment author hasn't deleted
        if comment.author.name in ignore_users:
            continue

    alerted_comments.append(comment.id)

    if len(alerted_comments) > 100:
         alerted_comments = alerted_comments[-100:]

         with open(save_path, 'w') as fp:
             json.dump(alerted_comments, fp)
        else:
             # You'll probably want to be more discerning than "not 200",
             # but that's fine for now.
             raise SlackError('Request to Slack returned an error %s, the response is:\n%s' % (response.status_code, response.text))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            main(save_path='alerted_comments.json')
        except Exception as e:
            print('There was an error: {}'.format(str(e)))
            time.sleep(60)  # wait for 60 seconds before restarting
```

What is meant to happen is, The script reads a keyword, and then puts that comment id of the keyword into the alerted_comments.json so it remembers and does not keep repeating the same keyword.

Comment: we need an example of your json, from error I can tell you that it is an object but you treat it like it's an array

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
The json actually starts as an empty file with only ```{}``` in the contents of the file. but once it starts adding data (not working as above), it looks like the following. 
```["eczsvni", "ed0m16d", "ed0q3x7", "ed20wq8"]```

Comment: try to initialize your empty file with `[]` instead of `{}`

Comment: Ok sure, ill give it a go!

Comment: Ahh amazing, such a tiny detail to overlook. thank you with helping. if you want to make that the answer Ill accept that. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an error we can find that we are working with `dict` instance when `list` was assumed, so the problem is in passed JSON or in our assumption about its structure.

From [conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55719997/attributeerror-dict-object-has-no-attribute-append-trying-to-write-to-json?noredirect=1#comment98119935_55719997) it becomes clear that initial JSON has

```
{}
```

empty object literal in its contents which becomes Python `dict` after deserialization with `json.load`, so if it should be an empty array instead we can replace contents with

```
[]
```